# Mongo count on collection or count on cursor - which faster

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I have question which counting method is faster:
I have some filter parameters called filterParameters.
Now I doing:

```
1. First option:
  int count = count with db.dbCollection.count(filterParameters) 
  and then 
  dbCursor = db.dbCollection.find(filterParameters).skip(..).limit(..)

2. Second way:
  dbCursor = db.dbCollection.find(filterParameters).skip(..).limit(..)
  int count = dbCursor.count()
```

And in Java, first way:

```
Integer countAllItems = documentService.count(documentType,filterQuery)
DBCursor documents = documentService.list(documentType, [:], filterQuery, sortQuery, command.start, command.count)
```

where: `documentService.count(documentType,filterQuery)` doing:

```
def collection = db.getCollection(documentType.collectionName)
collection.count(filterQuery)
```

and documentService.list is only find on collection.

And then second way:

```
DBCursor documents = documentService.list(documentType, [:], filterQuery, sortQuery, command.start, command.count)
Integer countAllItems = documents.count()
```

Which one is faster method ?

Answer (score 2):

Neither, the particular count you are using is a symlink for the cursor count, they are the same function.

Comment: Then the second should be faster? If you say that actually the `count` query is equivalent to `find` + cursor count (that is to say the "second way"), then the "first option" is equivalent to the second + another find query. Or am I mistaking somewhere? On top of that, doesn't mongo capitalize on his executed queries?

Comment: So I'm geting realy diffrent fealings, because when I used in java driver first option I'm geting hall time shorter than second option.

Comment: @dgiugg no, you only do one query in both methods

Comment: @dgiugg what you mean by capatalise? I am unsure as to how

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko How doesn't it?

Comment: @Sammaye, well, it seems I was mistaken... sorry